# How do I properly use distinct and compare?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using distinct which says

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

Yet when I run this code, I get multiple same id's

```
        var ls = ls2.Distinct().OrderByDescending(s => s.id);
        foreach (var v in ls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.id);
        }
```

I implemented these in my class yet this still doesnt work

```
class Post : IComparable<Post>, IEqualityComparer<Post>, IComparer<Post>
```

This is how I implemented it

```
                int IComparable<Post>.CompareTo(Post other)
                {
                    return (int)(id - other.id);
                }

                bool IEqualityComparer<Post>.Equals(Post x, Post y)
                {
                    return x.id == y.id;
                }

                int IEqualityComparer<Post>.GetHashCode(Post obj)
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }

                int IComparer<Post>.Compare(Post x, Post y)
                {
                    return (int)(x.id - y.id);
                }
```

Comment: According to the MSDN documentation, you only need to implement IEquatable<T> - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx for a fully worked example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly implement `GetHashCode()` in your comparer - in your case you can just return the hash code of the id:

```
int IEqualityComparer<Post>.GetHashCode(Post obj)
{
   return obj.id.GetHashCode();
}
```

Also as pointed out by @dash in a comment you need to implement `IEquatable<T>` in `Post` if you choose to go that route (option 1).

A comparer should be implemented in a separate class that you can then pass in in one of the `Distinct()` overloads (option 2), i.e. in your case could be class `MyPostComparer`:

```
var ls = ls2.Distinct(new MyPostComparer()).OrderByDescending(s => s.id);
```

A third option would be to use the [`DistinctBy()`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method of the MoreLinq project.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement `GetHashCode()`.

Since you're delegating to the `-` and the `==` why not just delegate to the appropriate functions in `id`. ie. `id.Compare(other.id)`, and `obj.id.GetHashCode()`, and delegate the Comparer to Compare. And also implement `IEquatable`

```
            int IComparable<Post>.CompareTo(Post other)
            {
                return id.Compare(other.id);
            }

            bool IEquatable<Post>.Equals(Post x)
            {
                return id == y.id;
            }


            bool IEqualityComparer<Post>.Equals(Post x, Post y)
            {
                return x.Equals(y.id);
            }

            int IEqualityComparer<Post>.GetHashCode(Post obj)
            {
                return obj.id.GetHashCode(); 
            }

            int IComparer<Post>.Compare(Post x, Post y)
            {
                return x.Compare(y);
            }
```

This assumes that id is an int, if not then you may have implement these for IEquatable for id too.

Comment: I'm pretty annoyed the comment in the ide/dll is incorrect. This is the first time i ever had to implement GetHashCode. Thanks

Comment: @Preet, you might want to fix IEqualityComparer<Post>.Equals to have "return x.Equals(y);" instead. Can't edit it because the change is only 3 characters.